# Plot observations in same x-axis point which linked with id variable

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I need help. This is a view of my database :

```
482 940 914  1  
507 824 1042 2   
514 730 1450 3  
477 595 913  4
```

My aim is to plot in the same point of x-axis each row.
Example:
in `1 (=x)` i want to plot `482`, `940` and `914`
in `2 (=x)` I want to plot `507`, `824` and `1042`.

So three points in vertical for each x axis points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a good idea to share the data in a reproducible way - I'm using `readClipboard` to read in the copied vector into R. Anyway, here's a quick answer:

```
x <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(readClipboard(), " ")))
```

This makes it into a numeric vector. We now need to split into groups based on the description you provided. I'm using `matrix` to achieve this and will then convert to `data.frame` for plotting using `ggplot2`:

```
m <- matrix(x, ncol = 4, byrow = T)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  482  940  914    1
[2,]  507  824 1042    2
[3,]  514  730 1450    3
[4,]  477  595  913    4

df <- as.data.frame(m)
# Assign names to the data.frame
names(df) <- letters[1:4]

> df
    a   b    c d
1 482 940  914 1
2 507 824 1042 2
3 514 730 1450 3
4 477 595  913 4
```

To get the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = d)) + 
    geom_point(aes(y = a), color = "red") + 
    geom_point(aes(y = b), color = "green")  + 
    geom_point(aes(y = c), color = "blue")
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

You can play around with `ggtitle` and `xlab` etc. to change the plot labels and add legends.

Hope this is helpful!